# Does constitution reduce magic missile's damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I am new to D&D. From what I've read, if I use magic missile against someone it will always hit, given that I am within range and I can see the creature.

One of the players told us that we were supposed to subtract the constitution modifier from magic missile's damage. So, if I choose to hit the same creature with three missiles, does this creature use its constitution modifier to diminish the damage for each missile or just once for the missiles?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Don't worry about having to learn stuff, it's perfectly reasonable. That's what being new to something is about, right? If you're interested in asking a lot of questions here, or looking around for ones that have already been asked, you could look at the [tour] and maybe read the [help].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Magic Missile is a first level spell that fires three magical force darts, which you can fire at one creature or you can spread them among multiple targets. At higher levels, you add another dart for each spell level beyond first level (second level magic missile produces **four** darts).

Each dart deals 1d4 + 1 Force damage to the target. It hits every time; you do not make a spell attack roll and targets do not make any saving throws.

One thing I see you are confused about is where you mention:

> "...does this creature use its constitution modifier to diminish the damage for each missile...?"

I am not sure where you are getting this from, actually, but ***normally creatures do not do that***. (There *is* a race called Goliath that has a feature *Stone's Endurance* which allows them to roll 1d12 + the Goliath's constitution modifier and reduce damage taken by that much (after which they must complete a short or long rest to use the feature again).)

Creatures hit by the darts from Magic Missile take the force damage rolled, after applying vulnerabilities and resistances, or they do not take said damage if they are immune or something specifically blocks it (like a Shield spell). Same goes for anything else that deals damage. If you have a Player's Handbook nearby that you can read, pretty much everything about Damage is described on Pages 196 and 197 under the section **Damage and Healing**. That chapter is for Combat, and earlier in the chapter it describes making attack rolls, movement in combat, actions you can take, and the like. The next chapter is on the rules of casting spells: targets, areas of effect, range, duration, casting time, components, etc. You may want to skim over these a little bit, or if you are feeling into it you can read through them completely.

Comment: It would also be good to point out that you roll the damage once and use that number for all of the darts.

Comment: @Doval If you mean that you roll 1d4+1 and each dart deals that much damage, I believe that is incorrect: excerpt from the spell "_a_ dart deals 1d4+1 force damage to its target." That means each dart deals its own separate damage.

Comment: From "Combat" > "Damage and Healing" in the Basic Rules: *“If a spell or other effect deals damage to more than one target at the same time, roll the damage once for all of them. For example, when a wizard casts fireball or a cleric casts flame strike, the spell’s damage is rolled once for all creatures caught in the blast.”* Magic Missile specifies the missiles strike simultaneously.  [Crawford has confirmed that's how the spell works.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/774030989894955008) (Whether it's one roll or many matters for features like Elemental Affinity.)

Comment: @Doval Source: https://mobile.twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/557823175581769729 or..rather...a second source

Comment: @Doval a magic missile *doesn't* "deal damage to more than one target", each missile damages one and only one target.

Comment: @DaleM The rule refers to *the spell* doing damage to more than one target at the same time. It doesn't matter that the missiles only strike one creature.

Comment: Doval has it right that this is RAW and RAI, confirmed by the designer multiple times. However, no table I've ever sat at has ever run it that way.

Comment: Because most dont; or do not care to, know any better. MM has been around for a LONG time in various editions and forms. It is often time a matter of thinking we know how it works because we have been using it for so long, instead of asking "how does THIS version work." Many AL tables I play at run MM damage exactly like this. But maybe they know better.

Comment: @Doval It is easy to see why many people would expect Magic Missile and multiple-ray spells to roll separately when the two examples in the section on damage rolls use two _Area_ spells, though. Also, many players are used to previous editions where everything did roll separate damage. I guess it was an unclear change.

Comment: @Javelin I fully agree that it's unexpected, that's why I brought it up. But on that note, [you *do* roll separately for spells with multiple attacks](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/671775187637932032).